# How can I add a highlight annotation to an existing PDF using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I want to add an annotation to an existing PDF, specifically a highlight annotation.
This is displayed as a translucent rectangle, marking one or more pieces of text.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library being used in this answer.

This answer uses `borb` a pure python PDF library.
Its code can be found [here](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb).

We start by reading the PDF:

```
doc = None
with open("input.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
    doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle)
```

Next we add the annotation:

```
# add annotation
doc.get_page(0).append_highlight_annotation(
    rectangle=Rectangle(
        Decimal(72.86), Decimal(486.82), Decimal(129), Decimal(13)
    ),
    contents="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet",
    color=X11Color("Yellow"),
)
```

Now we can store the PDF document again:

```
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as out_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, doc)
```

The output should look something like this (at least the annotation part):

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need `doc = None`

Comment: I also try to minimize the warnings I get when running static code analysis. I got a warning that doc was potentially undefined. So I added the `doc = None`